# Remove the last color form bitmap Undo

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Please I need the help regarding Undo method , I tried to implement it like the code below but it is not remove the last color,
Kindly help me to resolve it.

awaiting your kind response.

Thanks in Advance.

---

**MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 View.OnTouchListener {
Button red, blue, yellow, undo;
Paint paint;
private RelativeLayout drawingLayout;
private MyView myView;
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
  /*
  *
  * private ImageView imageView; private Canvas cv; private Bitmap mask,
  * original, colored; private int r,g,b; private int sG, sR, sB;
  */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myView = new MyView(this);
    drawingLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    drawingLayout.addView(myView);

    red = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_red);
    blue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_blue);
    yellow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yellow);
    undo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.undo);

    red.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });

    yellow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    });
    blue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
    undo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myView.onClickUndo();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


// flood fill
public class MyView extends View {

    final Point p1 = new Point();
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Canvas canvas;
    private Path path;

    // Bitmap mutableBitmap ;
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.gp1_1).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        this.path = new Path();


    }

    public void onClickUndo() {
        if (paths.size() > 0) {
            undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.nomore), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      //   int width = drawingLayout.getWidth();
     // int height = drawingLayout.getHeight();
    // float centerX = (width - mBitmap.getWidth()) * 0.5f;
    //float centerY = (height - mBitmap.getHeight()) * 0.5f;
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
        ///////////////////////////////
        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
            //////////////////////////
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                p1.x = (int) x;
                p1.y = (int) y;
                final int sourceColor = mBitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
                final int targetColor = paint.getColor();
                new TheTask(mBitmap, p1, sourceColor, targetColor).execute();
                paths.add(path);

                invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getCurrentPaintColor() {
        return paint.getColor();
    }

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        Bitmap bmp;
        Point pt;
        int replacementColor, targetColor;

        public TheTask(Bitmap bm, Point p, int sc, int tc) {
            this.bmp = bm;
            this.pt = p;
            this.replacementColor = tc;
            this.targetColor = sc;
            pd.setMessage(getString(R.string.wait));
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            FloodFill f = new FloodFill();
            f.floodFill(bmp, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}

public class FloodFill {
    public void floodFill(Bitmap image, Point node, int targetColor,
                          int replacementColor) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int target = targetColor;
        int replacement = replacementColor;
        if (target != replacement) {
            Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<Point>();
            do {

                int x = node.x;
                int y = node.y;
                while (x > 0 && image.getPixel(x - 1, y) == target) {
                    x--;

                }
                boolean spanUp = false;
                boolean spanDown = false;
                while (x < width && image.getPixel(x, y) == target) {
                    image.setPixel(x, y, replacement);
                    if (!spanUp && y > 0
                            && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
                        spanUp = true;
                    } else if (spanUp && y > 0
                            && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) != target) {
                        spanUp = false;
                    }
                    if (!spanDown && y < height - 1
                            && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
                        spanDown = true;
                    } else if (spanDown && y < height - 1
                            && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) != target) {
                        spanDown = false;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            } while ((node = queue.poll()) != null);
        }
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: "Not working" as in...?

Comment: @LunarWatcher Could you please explain more?

Comment: That is what I am asking you to. You write: `the undo method not working` - what is not working? IS it a crash? Exception at least? Or does it simply do nothing?

Comment: @LunarWatcher   
It is not remove the last added color to canvas, it just delete path from array without any effect on bitmap

Comment: @cricket_007 Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is impossible to return previous color it is required an array for each point to store the used color in every point.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the undo method doesn't work. The possible reason is the previous drawing on the canvas is not removed. Try clearing the canvas before drawing in the `onDraw()` method.

```
 @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
 this.canvas = canvas;   
canvas. drawColor(0,PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); //This clears the canvas.
 paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
 //rest of the code
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for trying helping me but it's showing full black screen.